# Prerequisites to study aesthetics

Tags: reference-request, aesthetics, critical-theory

So, I plan to begin to self study aesthetics, and was wondering whether a working knowledge of art history would be helpful for the same? If so, would Gardner's History of Art be sufficient?
Also, on a bit of a related note, would knowledge of critical theory be helpful?

Comment: I think Gardner's is an excellent book.  I don't think you need to study critical theory, maybe at some point, but it is not necessary for a beginning. Music: Second Viennese School:  http://www3.northern.edu/robert.vodnoy/music%20history%20iv/tonal%20and%20post-tonal%20music.doc , Archtecture:  https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.theartstory.org/amp/movement-bauhaus.htm Gropius later married Mahler's wife, a situation wherein Freud gave assistance to Mahler.

Comment: I would use Vienna 1900-1914, its history,  as a nexus, because it pays many dividends later on, but this is up to your personal taste. You can also study Apollinaire and "On the Subject of Modern Painting" http://mariabuszek.com/mariabuszek/kcai/DadaSurrealism/DadaSurrReadings/ApolPtg.pdf, and Baudelaire: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Baudelaire, EA Poe too.

Comment: For an anti-modern you could study TS Eliot. This is just one way to slice the cake, to give you some content for the study of philosophy, aesthetics itself.

Comment: "Discovering Music, Early 20th Century. https://www.bl.uk/20th-century-music/articles/the-second-viennese-school

Comment: @Gordon : Gardner (OP's choice) is really broad in time and space. Your recommendations particularly Schoenberg's music school is super  avant garde modern. I would question the optimality of such recommendations. Of course he did ask about critical theory... So there's that slant

Comment: Thank you for informing me, I was curious as to why I was getting only Avant - garde recommendations. Would you know of any references on art history from the medieval era to Impressionism, maybe?

Comment: I am not one who should recommend... Anyways... I'd stay close to the Greeks -- Aristotle Plato...

Comment: Gardner's is a very good book, but it's been a while since I read mine. It was a school text. Sure, there are many ways to approach this, you mentioned critical theory and some of the "avant" content may be helpful. If you can get to a college or good local library (Main Branch) they should be running over with books on art, including the philosophical topics. The libraries usually retain these books since many are expensive. Good luck!

Comment: You may want to look into Aristotle's Aesthetics and become familiar with 'mimesis'. CMS